# Perform an action every day after Sep 5

Tags: c++, winapi

I need to perform an action every day after September 5. I wrote this program

```
#include <windows.h>

int main()
{
    SYSTEMTIME time;
    GetLocalTime(&time);

    if((time.wMonth = 9 && time.wDay >= 6) || time.wMonth > 9)
    {
        //perform action
        MessageBox(GetForegroundWindow(), "Action performed. Month is " + std::to_string((long long)wMonth), "Alarm!", MB_OK | MB_SYSTEMMODAL);
    }
}
```

I ran this program and the message box displays. But today is August 22, I checked my computer's clock. What am I doing wrong?

Reference [SYSTEMTIME](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724950%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Update:
After writing this question I checked the values of wMonth and wDay and these are 1 and 22, i.e. Jan 22.
Seems like a bug. What do I do to get correct month?

Comment: I got it, given the order of precedence of operators, time.wDay >= 6 is evaluated first to give 1(true) since today is 22, then 9 && 1 which gives 1. So wMonth becomes 1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`if((time.wMonth = 9 ...` needs to be :

```
if((time.wMonth == 9 ...
               ^^^^
```

If you reverse your test (and many C++ programmers do), the compiler will emit an error :

```
if((9 = time.wMonth ...  // error !
```

Which is a way of catching this frequent typo.

Comment: You can get some help from your compiler when you write 9 == time.wMonth instead, because 9 = time.wMonth will create a compiler error.

Comment: Ah! problem solved. Now, I wonder why wMonth became 1 while the expression was wMonth = 9.

Comment: The assignment result if the value being assigned (to allow chaining), so you basically checked `if(9 && ...` hope it helps.

Comment: I have updated the code, the result I was getting was "Action performed. Month is 1". Why it showed month is 1(Jan), rather than 9(Sept)? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think is better to use the cron manager (Linux) or Task Manager (Windows) to schedule your job

Comment: On windows it is Task Scheduler.